# Build Automation Process

Tags: git, build, build-automation, git-flow

This is in regards to best practices related to application building. We are following the [git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/) principle of development. We use bamboo to build but that doesn't really matter. My question is, is it generally better to have scheduled builds or automated builds or manual builds? I personally think automated or manual builds are the way to go and here's why.

Automated builds will poll a particular branch (most likely the develop branch) and when it detects a change it will initiate a build. This is great because you always create a build when there's new code to build. The bad side is if you have a team of 5 and everyone merges their feature branch into develop 1 minute after each other then you'll have 5 different builds.

Which leads me to why I believe manual builds are the best. Once you've got everyone's changes in you can kick off a build. This will keep the number of builds small.

What does SO think about the options? Which one is the standard industry practice for an efficient CI/CD team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think any opinion on how you manage builds depends on what you value in your process and that is not clear from your question.

As an aside; most build systems do not require a distinct build for every commit. If you have multiple commits to development within your polling interval you should be able to test/deploy them all as one build. This could be good or bad for you.

**Continuous Integration**

Continuous integration should give you a smoother and faster development process with the assurance that your project is in a releasable state (or at least passing its own tests, hopefully that's the same thing). I've found that manual builds routinely fail to enforce the same level of quality. It's all too easy to commit breaking changes "knowing" that it will be fixed before the next manual build which then starts slipping further and further away or when a build does fail it's suddenly unclear which of several changes introduced the failure. For continuous integration I would expect not only automated builds of your development branch but automated builds of every feature branch showing that they pass your tests before they are merged into development.

In many environments it's possible for the cost of a CI build to be negligible compared to the cost of the development team's time. For example I'm currently looking at a project averaging around 5 active committers and only 12 builds per day over the past 4 years or so. Keeping tests fast and reliable isn't easy but running lots of builds (concurrently in the case of feature branches) should be.

There are environments where the process of testing a build can't be cheap or fast e.g. you need to run hardware tests or performance tests which take hours. In those cases you need a different approach but you're also probably not actually able to practice continuous integration and your development/branching strategy should reflect that.

**Continuous Delivery**

Continuous delivery goes a step further and shortens the cycle time from development to changes reaching your users by deploying all of those releasable builds. If there is a manual step in the process of releasing (or rolling back) those builds then I don't believe you should call your process "continuous delivery".

You can have a very nice automated deploy process without it being continuous. Continuous delivery can be very valuable for some products but can also be disruptive and a poor fit for others. For example we currently continuously deploy to a consumer facing web app. We also maintain backend operations tools where we are more conservative about when to release (or at least when to enable new features) since changes to those tools can introduce new workflows that we don't want to appear in the middle of someone's shift without warning.

**tl;dr**

Automate everything, don't slow your team down by trying to keep the number of builds small.